# Why are my EIP-712 signatures different in Ruby and JavaScript?

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, signature, ruby

I'm trying to sign data using EIP-712 standard and my signatures from Ruby and JavaScript don't match when the data is in bytes. They work fine when the data is a string. I'm using `eth.rb` in Ruby and `ethers.js` in JavaScript. Here's what my code looks like:

**Ruby:**

```ruby
require 'eth'

WALLET_PRIV_KEY = "9254e66d59eae01a70e3fc9e74b88d5a14b2a6d998b391b1c02c67e26e1197ec"
wallet = Eth::Key.new(priv: WALLET_PRIV_KEY)

# Define the data structure
data = {
  types: {
    EIP712Domain: [
      { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
      { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' },
    ],
    Data: [
       { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
     ],
  },
  primaryType: 'Data',
  domain: {
    name: 'Complex Data',
    version: '1',
    chainId: 421613,  # Make sure the chainId matches your Ethereum network
    verifyingContract: '0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC',
  },
  message: {
    data: "0xa2d6eae3",
  }
}

# Sign the typed data
signature = wallet.sign_typed_data(data)

puts 'Signature:', signature
=> cfd37db77ba39226630b60844b4dc917389a95c868146e1574a5deee571d095837c017c3d13f870b37c9d47c75f0c5b87175a81af047dbcfa8c694efb62e81150cddfe
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');

const PRIVATE_KEY = "9254e66d59eae01a70e3fc9e74b88d5a14b2a6d998b391b1c02c67e26e1197ec";
const domain = {
    name: 'Complex Data',
    version: '1',
    chainId: 421613,
    verifyingContract: '0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC'
};

const types = {
  Data: [
        { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
    ]
};

const value = {
  data: "0xa2d6eae3",
};

async function signTypedData() {
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY);
    const signature = await wallet.signTypedData(domain, types, value);
    console.log('Signature:', signature);
}

signTypedData();

=> 0xb508986924836784c31beb8034481db598374a8698e74ef85d05081fcb21df9d3cf7c83299c3260dc4bf7e6ea65acc8e2645f452ca653519a7116c9acac745971c
```

Can someone help me figure out why the signatures are different?